# Unix regex to list only directories with a valid version name

Tags: regex, grep

I have version directories with various naming conventions.

Example:

```
1.0.1
10.10.12.3
11.0.9
11.10.99
1111.12.33
2.1.0
```

I want a pattern that will only return those with a valid version of major.minor.revision and no more than 2 digits between. In other words, I only want to return the following from list above:

```
1.0.1
11.0.9
11.10.99
2.1.0
```

I am using the following line currently, but it is returning all of them:

```
ls -d */ | grep '\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\(\.[0-9]\{1,2\}\)\(\.[0-9]\{1,2\}\)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you forgot to tell `grep` to check from the **beginning** to the **end** of the line by surrounding your pattern with `^` and `$`:

```
ls -d */ | grep '^\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\(\.[0-9]\{1,2\}\)\(\.[0-9]\{1,2\}\)/$'
```

Otherwise:

- `1111.12.33` will match because it contains *at least* `1.12.3`
- `10.10.12.3` will match because it contains *at least* `10.10.1` or

By the way, you don't need parenthesis here. Also add a backslash to ls to use the executable and not an alias, and pass to it `-1` to be sure your directory content will be displayed on one colunm, each entry per line:

```
\ls -d1 */ | grep '^[0-9]\{1,2\}\.[0-9]\{1,2\}\.[0-9]\{1,2\}/$'
```

You could also check the last two numbers with the same regex, and then use parenthesis to double it with `{2}`. Finally, pass the parameter `-E` (for ***e***xtended regexes) to get ride of all those extra slashes:

```
\ls -d1 */ | grep '^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2}){2}/$'
```

---

If you want to get ride of the trailing slashes `/`, either write `\ls -d1 *` if you have just version directories (and no version files *named the same way*) or replace the grep call with a sed one. Pick the one which fits the requirements.

- No version-like filenames:

  ```
  \ls -d1 *  | grep -E '^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2}){2}$'
  ```
- Version-like filenames:

  ```
  \ls -d1 */ | sed -rn 's/^([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2}){2})\/?$/\1/p'
  ```

Comment: it doesn't return anything when I use those beginning and ending operators?

Comment: ok, much better. I can't use the -o option though as it still returns that directory - just without the unmatching portion of it. So it returns 

1.0.1
10.10.12 (this isn't valid though)
11.0.9
11.10.99
2.1.0

Comment: No. there will be a little bit of everything out there. cleaning up a lot of junk dirs. there will be alpha, alpha/numeric, any mix imaginable. There will also be files

Comment: Brilliant @Amessihel! Your updated answer works. It was the forward slash with the end of line $. Thanks!

Comment: @JVipe, you're welcome! By the way anubhava's answer was better, the only issue seems to come from the version we use. I still don't understand why it doesn't work. Probably worth of a SO question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `bash` then you can use this glob pattern with extended glob:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' [0-9]?([0-9]).[0-9]?([0-9]).[0-9]?([0-9])
```

```
1.0.1
11.0.9
11.10.99
2.1.0
```

else if you have `gnu find` then you may just use:

```
find . -type d -regextype egrep -regex '^\./([0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}$'
```

If you're on OSX then use this `find` command:

```
find -E . -type d -regex '^\./([0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}$'
```

Comment: Funny, I tried the `gnu find` line, and it doesn't work here... I even tried to escape the curly braces and changed the `-regextype` value... What is your version of `find`? Mine is `4.4.2`.

Comment: @anubhava, this line doesn't work too. I'm surprised too, curly braces should be supported...

Comment: Can you try this: `find . -regextype gnu-awk -regex '.*/[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}$'`

Comment: @anubhava, I'm sorry... Both of your last lines don't work. I checked again, it's `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`. Features enabled: `D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION CBO(level=0)`

Comment: I have tried same command on OSX (gnu-find) and on Ubuntu and it worked both times though I have version `4.7.0` on both systems.

Comment: @anubhava, just in case: of course your solution is better since it relies on one single command.